# Find match of an array in another array recursively not working

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find match of an array against another array recursively but the code fails and throws an error if the match doesn't find. Here's my complete code which only works when a match is found otherwise recursive function doesn't work for finding some another match.

```
<?php
$products = array(
                191 => array(2),
                192 => array(2,1),
                237 => array(2,3),
                238 => array(2,3,1),
                239 => array(1,2),
                266 => array()
            );


$options = array(1,2,3);
sort($options);

echo find_product($options, $products);

function find_product($options, $products)
{
    foreach($products as $key => $value)
    {
        sort($value);
        if($value == $options)
        {
            $product_id = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isset($product_id))
    {
        array_pop($options);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($options);
        //print_r($products);
        echo "</pre>";
        find_product($options, $products);
    }
    return $product_id;
}
?>
```

output is 238, but when I commented the array element

```
//238 => array(2,3,1),
```

I'm getting following error

```
 Notice: Undefined variable: product_id in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 37
```

Expected output should be

239

How I can fix it to work with recursive function to find some other match?

Comment: But 239 is not a match.

Comment: when the last element is removed from `$options = array(1,2,3);` its match is found in `239 => array(1,2),` so the result should be 239, that's i want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to make this a lot easier, you just have to add one more nesting-layer to your `$options` array:

```
<?php
$products = array(
                191 => array(2),
                192 => array(2,1),
                237 => array(2,3),
                238 => array(2,3,1),
                239 => array(1,2),
                266 => array()
            );


$options = array(1,2,3);
sort($options);

$resultArr = array_intersect(array($options), $products);

// this last part assigns the value that you were previously returning
if (count($resultArr) == 1) {
    $yourKey = array_keys($resultArr)[0];
}
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve, can't do with recursion?

Comment: By definition, no it can't be done with recursion since your array is not suited for it. Array_intersect is a far better solution as long as your array has that structure.